# Check if wifi is on or not inside a class in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this class:

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService;

public class Wifi {

    public static boolean isOn() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        return wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    }

}
```

I want to return the state of wifi using this class and method. But I get an error for `getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)` part:

`Error: The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application context or memory will leak on devices`

Answer (score 0):

Use .getApplicationContext().getSystemService instead.

Comment: Instead of which part exactly?

Comment: WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); ====> WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: You can rewrite your code like this 
public static boolean isOn(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        return wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    }

But when you use it inside fragment / activity, use like this Wifi.isOn(getApplicationContext())